# SystemAccessViolation Exception With MSR605X

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I'm currently trying to write a Windows Forms Application that can read/write magstripe card data with the Deftun MSR605X. It comes with a default program, MSRX. It works perfectly, but as a coding project, I wanted to do a clone of it. It came with a `MagAPI.dll`, which I used Dependency Walker to view the function names.

When trying to initialize communication to the device, using `MSR_InitComm(productId, vendorId)`, I am getting the SystemAccessViolation exception. MSR_InitComm returns a value of `-36` instead of the expected `0`.

I have tried reading the documentation at [https://www.triades.net/downloads/MSR605%20Programmer's%20Manual.pdf](https://www.triades.net/downloads/MSR605%20Programmer%27s%20Manual.pdf), I have tried googling the problem (but it is very niche), and I have even tried with ChatGPT. Neither of these sources gave any clarity on the `-36` response code or why the InitComm will not work.

Even when catching the exception with the following code, the program still crashes and never gets to the MessageBox.

```
try
            {
                // Find the device
                handle = MSR_InitComm(vendorId, productId);
            }
            catch (System.AccessViolationException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception here
                MessageBox.Show("Access violation error: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

The program is able to detect the writer properly when it is connected via USB, and the MSRX program works perfectly. But InitComm refuses to work.

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CardReaderApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private IntPtr handle;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int vendorId = 0x0801;
            int productId = 0x0003;

            // Find the device
            try
            {
                // Find the device
                handle = MSR_InitComm(vendorId, productId);
            }
            catch (System.AccessViolationException ex)
            {
                // Handle exception here
                MessageBox.Show("Access violation error: " + ex.Message);
            }

            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "MSR605X connected\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Failed to connect to MSR605X\r\n";
            }
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Release the device handle when closing the form
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MSR_ExitComm(handle);
            }

            base.OnFormClosing(e);
        }

        private void ReadData()
        {
            // Read data from the device
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int length = MSR_Read(handle, data, data.Length);

            // TODO: Process the received data
        }

        // Import the functions from the MagAPI.dll using P/Invoke
        [DllImport("MagAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "MSR_InitComm", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern IntPtr MSR_InitComm(int vendorId, int productId);

        [DllImport("MagAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "MSR_ExitComm", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern void MSR_ExitComm(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("MagAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "MSR_Read", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int MSR_Read(IntPtr handle, byte[] data, int length);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the spec: *Standard RS232 signal voltage levels. Default, 9600 Baud, None Parity, 8 bits*  I would look for on what COM port that device gets connected and then use the command strings in Section 6 and further. Much more chance to get that working instead of trying to reverse engineer a dll that obviously isn't designed for the goal you're trying to use it. For direction: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+rs232

Comment: @rene The device doesn't attach to a COM Port. It is recognized as an HID Device. In Device Managers, it is under the HID section as "USB Input Device". It has no references in the COM Port section. Which is why I'm using HIDSharp and this .dll work around. I can't find a proper method that doesn't ask for a COM port. Also, I don't understand why it's "obviously not designed" for this purpose? I'm only trying to make a clone program, no new functionalities.